# Efficient way of summing the values in specified ranges of a column

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, sum

Given an array like the following:

```
a = np.array([[1,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,1],
              [1,0,0,0],
              [0,1,0,0],
              [0,0,1,0],
              [1,0,0,0]])
```

I.e. you only have `1` in only one column per row.

Is there a more efficient way (in terms of computation time) of summing the values than the following:

```
required_sum = sum(1 for x in a[large_range_of_rows,column_of_interest] if item==1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you wrote is indeed relatively inefficient, as it drops out of `numpy` and into standard Python (which is slooooow).

The following will do it all in `numpy`:

```
>>> (a[0:2, 1:4] == 1).sum()
1
```